# Disable or Remove Edit top 200 Rows option from SSMS

Tags: ssms, features

I have already done some R&D on the same but don't have the real solution. Is there a way to obsolete the right click option "Edit Top 200 Rows" from SSMS?

The goal is to prevent developers from changing data using that option. We can't just restrict their permissions. Developers are required to have the edit rights but they are lazy and we can't track the changes if they edit records with that option. (We are tracking the changes using a paid SSMS extension.)